# ODK creating a test - can I randomize the order?

Tags: xml, odk

Using the below xml file I created a test for users to see an image, say if a condition was absent or present, and then grade them.

Given folks are now taking this test at home, I would like to randomize the order of the questions. Is it possible to create an array or something similar to so that I could randomize the order?

Thanks!

Code example here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/12lLAsAoBtm__ING37jujg2ulU26K9ah1je_ySLabS1c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to randomize the order and show all 50 questions to all respondents, this is not possible.

There is a workaround to create lots of groups with different orders of the same 50 questions and then use a relevant to only show one randomly selected group, but it's rather cumbersome.

If you'd like to only show 10 (out of 50) randomly selected questions that is possible using random() and relevant.

May be worth checking the [ODK Forum](https://forum.getodk.org/) as well. Lots of clever form builders willing to help.